# Xamarin forms design

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

[Split Screen option is unavailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfsdL.png)

Before I update visual studio 2019 I used to find the Split Screen options for XAML code to view the design of my content pages next to their XAML code using Xaml hot Previewer

[Those options are not available anymore when I open a XAML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4CWG.png)

one day I've updated visual studio than when I opened a XAML file, the design mode is not available
anymore

Ps: it works when I open a XAML file for a UWP project it works but for a Xamarin forms android or IOS platform it doesn't work

Comment: Is it helpful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

The XAML Previewer has been deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.8, and replaced by the **XAML Hot Reload** feature in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9.

For now, it use the **Hot Reload** insead and provide a live visual tree to receive a real-time view of your running XAML code. It shows a tree view of the UI elements of your running Xamarin.Forms application.

You could learn more about **XAML Hot Reload** in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload).